# Can Nest's ClientsModule be imported globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, microservices

According to the official example, by registering like this, ClientsModule can be used in AppModule. However, if I have other modules with different functionalities that also need to use ClientProxy and I only register it in AppModule, an error will occur. (I have imported all my modules in AppModule.)

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      { name: 'MATH_SERVICE', transport: Transport.TCP },
    ]),
  ]
  ...
})
```

A method that can import clientmodule globally

Answer (score 1):

Currently, no, **but** you can make a global wrapper for it.

```js
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [ClientsModule.register(options)],
  exports: [ClientsModule],
})
export class GlobalClientsModule {}
```

Now add `GlobalClientsModule` to the `imports` of your `AppModule` and you've got it globally set.